# is there a limit on number of simultaneous pdo persistent connections?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

when using persistent connections with PDO (with mysql), is there a limit on the number of databases that can have simultaneous persistent connections?  (if so, where can that be set)?

Comment: What made you ask this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connections aren't limited by PDO; The MySQL driver is. MySQL also can be configured to set the maximum amount.

In `my.ini`, you can edit the `max_connections` directive.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Appreciate it. That is helpful.

Comment: You say `The MySQL driver is`: can you point to a configuration stating the number of connections MySQL driver can use (besides setting it on MySQL server side in my.ini)?